# How to create an Empty Array to store values calculated from the given from program in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having difficulties initializing an array to how values given from a for loop, I want to discard the prime numbers calculated and then keep the non prime numbers in an array, which the size of the array must be unknown from the beginning. I must then call collect the numbers from the array and then apply the Carmichael equation to them to find Carmichael numbers.

Applying the equation to the values in the array is what I am finding difficult as well.
This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int a ,b;
    int notPrime[] = {};
    printf("Type in two non negative intergers: \n");
    scanf("%d" "%d", &a , &b);
    int i=a , k=0 ,count=0, j, p, m;
    for (i < b;){    //from the integers given b must be the larger of the two 
        if (i==0 || i==1) {  //to calculte the prime numbers
            notPrime[k]=i;
        }else{
            for( j=2;j<i;j++){
                if(i%j==0){
                    break;
                }else{
                    notPrime[k]=i;
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    p=0;
    if (p<=k){
        for (m=1;m<notPrime[p];m++){
            if((pow(m,notPrime[p])-m)%notPrime[p]==0){ //use of the values in the array and use of the carmichael equation
                count=count+1;
            }
            if(count==notPrime[p]-1){
                Printf( "%d \n", &notPrime[p]) ;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i have errors on `for (i < b;){`, `if((pow(m,notPrime[p])-m)%notPrime[p]==0){` and finally the print statment `Printf( "%d \n", &notPrime[p])`

Please could I get a little help, just set me in the right direction and I will try to correct.

xRapture

Comment: `for (i < b;)` is not valid C. `printf` does not start with a capital. What error you get on `if((pow...`?

Comment: This is such fundamental stuff that you really have to step back and read the first chapters of your C programming book one more time.

Comment: I sometimes fail to understand minor concepts and feel as though I am not making too much progress in my programming.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i < b;){
```

This is not a valid syntax for `for` loop . You can write like this instead -

```
for (;i < b;){
```

And this -

```
if((pow(m,notPrime[p])-m)%notPrime[p]==0){ //
```

`pow` return `double` and `notPrime[p]` is `int` . `%` operator on `double` and `int` .

Explicitly cast result of `pow` to `int`.

Also this -

```
 printf( "%d \n", &notPrime[p]) ;
                  ^ this is not needed
```

don't pass address of `int`.

### Edit -

You can declare your array as this after taking input `a` and `b` -

```
 int notPrime[a] = {0};           // or size b as you desire
```

Comment: I set the pow to int like so `if(((int)pow(m,notPrime[p])-m)%notPrime[p]==0){` and the compiler accepted it but can you perform such calculations on and array and expect the elements in the array to change?

Comment: @PhilipDyson You are not performing calculatons on array but on its elements . `notPrime[p]` is an array element not array .

Comment: Got an error when compiling in the linux terminal stating zero or negative array in `int nonPrime[] = {}`. that's what I was afraid of.

Comment: @PhilipDyson  I was about to ask about that declaration . Change that . Mention size of array and inititalize it .

Comment: To mention the size of the array I need to know the input of "a" and "b" should I then change it to a dynamic array?

Comment: @PhilipDyson  After taking input you can declare the array . no problem in that . VLAs are supported from C99 .

Comment: If you can't use C99 variable length arrays, you can use the `calloc` function to allocate storage for a variable length on the stack. `calloc` returns a pointer, but if you store that in an `int *notPrime` variable, you can still use `notPrime[n]` to access the `n`th element, just like an array.

Comment: When giving the array size I am liable to give it a very large size for example 10000 be cause the first and second Carmichael numbers are 561 and 1105. If the user where to put in one and one million for example I would get an error for sure.

Comment: @PhilipDyson `10000` may not cause problem , but if size may b e bigger than that , for sure use dynamic allocation for that .

Comment: @ameyCU Will apply the dynamic allocation and if I encounter more problems with the code I will leave a comment.